# Laravel 5 SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found

Tags: php, sql, laravel, join, query-builder

I am doing some joins and trying to get the data. My query builder is:

```
$datasource = DB::table('vehicles')->join('brands', 'vehicles.brand_id', '=', 'brands.id')->join('sections', 'vehicles.section_id', '=', 'sections.id')->select('vehicles.*, vehicles.id AS vid');
```

But i am getting this error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'vehicles.model,' in 'field list' (SQL: select `vehicles`.`model,` as
>   `AS` from `vehicles` inner join `brands` on `vehicles`.`brand_id` =
>   `brands`.`id` inner join `sections` on `vehicles`.`section_id` =
>   `sections`.`id` limit 4 offset 0) Line 620

What i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `selectRaw()` instead of `select()`:

```
->selectRaw('vehicles.*, vehicles.id AS vid');
```

Read more about raw expressions: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#raw-expressions